# Disable submit button in JavaScript until user share the facebook page.

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

My Question is:

How to Disable submit button in JavaScript until user share the facebook page.

I am using radio buttion for show/hide facebook share button.

---------JavaScript for show/hide the div----------------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="low"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".low").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="high"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".high").show();
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

---------css----------------

```
.box{
        padding: 5px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width:80%;
    }
```

------------html---------------

```
<label><input type="radio" name="priority" value="low" id="priority_0" />Low</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="priority" value="high" id="priority_0" />High</label>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="adbtn" value="" />

<div class="low"></div>
<div class="high box">Here is facebook page link to be share </div>
```

I want when the user click on the high radio button then submit button should be disabled. then user share the page on facebook after sharing the page the submit button get enabled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
            if($(this).val()=="low"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".low").show();
                $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
           else if($(this).val()=="high"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".high").show();
                $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Use **'change'** instead of **'click'** event.

Comment: your code just allow the button disabled when click on high, but not get enabled after sharing page on facebook @RGS

Comment: @FarwallGhost, Use $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled'); to enable submit button after sharing.

Comment: how the page will detect whether user shared the facebook page or not?? @RGS